# Docker networking via SSL

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have two docker containers that share the same network. When I ssh into one of the containers make a http call to the other, I get 200 response: `curl -i http://app-web`.

I need to be able to call app-web container via https: `curl https://app-web`, however that returns: `Failed to connect to app-web port 443: Connection refused`.

This is the docker-compose.yml file for the `app-web`. What am I missing?

```
version: "3.8"

networks:
  local-proxy:
    external: true
  internal:
    external: false

services:
    web:
        build:
            context: ./docker/bin/php
        container_name: app-web"
        expose:
            - "80"
            - "443"
        networks:
            - internal
            - local-proxy
```

Comment: Your application isn't listening on port 443.  Compose `expose:` does pretty much nothing at all, and you can delete that section of the file without changing anything about how the containers work.

Comment: @DavidMaze I figured that much, but I left it there to point out that I've tried exposing 443 to no avail. My question still stands: how do I get it to work via https call? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As stated by [@David Maze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71534226/docker-networking-via-ssl?noredirect=1#comment126431479_71534226)

> Your application isn't listening on port 443. Compose `expose:` does
> pretty much nothing at all, and you can delete that section of the
> file without changing anything about how the containers work.

You need to make sure that the `app-web` container is set up and actually listening on port `443`.

For example, for Apache, this may mean:

1. Enabling the necessary modules. I.e. `a2enmod headers ssl`.
2. Setting up that domain to be able to handle/receive SSL connections.
3. Restarting your server to implement the changes.

More to that here. [How To Create a Self-Signed SSL Certificate for Apache in Ubuntu 18.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-apache-in-ubuntu-18-04)